# Unable to connect to xmlrpc in Apache Karaf

Tags: java, xml-rpc, karaf

I am trying to connect to an XmlRpc server with this https://github.com/Navds/odooxmlrpc

It is working when executed standalone but when I bundle it to Karaf, the connection hangs infinitely. I don't have any clue about what is happening.

In the following code:

```
LOGGER.info("Sending request...");
Object res = client.execute(commonConfig, "login", params);
LOGGER.info("Response received.");
```

the log "Response received" is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was due to xml-apis conflict. Solved it by removing it from the bundle dependency..